# New image every day

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to see new image every day in my app. I'm trying to use the code below, but it doesn't work. Where am I wrong?

I also want that user can see new image only if he opens my app every day (1st day - image1, 2nd day - image2, 3rd day - image3 and etc). But, for example, if he didn't open on the 3rd day, but opened on the 4th day, then he will start from image1. How is it possible to implement this in code?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageName: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }


    func getImageForToday() -> UIImage {
        let arrImages = ["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg", "image3.jpg", "image4.jpg", "image5.jpg"]

        let imageName = arrImages[getLastCharacterFromTodayDate()]
        return UIImage(named: imageName)!
    }


    func getLastCharacterFromTodayDate() -> Int {
        let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendar.Identifier.gregorian)!
        let component = calendar.components(NSCalendar.Unit.calendar, from: NSDate() as Date)
        return component.day! % 10
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite clear why you are using

```
return component.day! % 10
```

from

> getLastCharacterFromTodayDate()

Therefore I would return the Integer equivalent of the day from that function as

```
func getLastCharacterFromTodayDate() -> Int {
    let calendar = Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent
    return calendar.component(.weekday, from: Date() )
}
```

then make a minor change to

> getImageForToday

```
func getImageForToday() -> UIImage {
    let arrImages = ["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg", "image3.jpg", "image4.jpg", "image5.jpg"]
    let imageName = arrImages[getLastCharacterFromTodayDate() % arrImages.count]
    return UIImage(named: imageName)!
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But it doesn’t work. Tell me please where is an error?

Answer (score 0):

Your code `let component = calendar.components(NSCalendar.Unit.calendar, from: NSDate() as Date)`the first parameter may be should be change into `.day`
And then make a small change in the following two places:
1.

```
func getLastCharacterFromTodayDate() -> Int {
    let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendar.Identifier.gregorian)!
    let component = calendar.components(.day, from: Date())
    return component.day!
}
```

2.

```
let imageName = arrImages[getLastCharacterFromTodayDate() % arrImages.count]
```

Comment: Thanks! But it doesn’t works. Tell me please where is an error?

Answer (score 0):

I thinks its better to save time and user open the app on userpreference.
if the date change more than 24 hours... you can set it back to first image. 
if the date change less than 24 hours... you can set next image.

Thanks